# Nexus 3 do not support npm dist-tags commands

Tags: node.js, npm, nexus, shippable-ci

My question is related to this [nexus 3 reported issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9862). Nexus 3 doesn't support npm distags and no fix is announced.

We are working with nexus 2 in production and we publish our npm packages using [npm dist-tags](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/dist-tag) via Shippable builds pipeline.

We have multiple streams of development and we use tags to represent each of them (alpha -> rc -> master) and this is combined with npm versioning.
This allows us to provide an alias instead of version numbers in the build scripts.

For example, to publish a package we use this :

```
npm publish module1 --tag=alpha
```

And then during dependecy install :

```
npm install module1@alpha
```

It works perfectly with nexus 2, after an upgrade to nexus 3 it doesn't work (can not pull a package using a specific tag : npm install module1@alpha.)

This is mandatory for us to migrate our npm registry to Nexus 3.

Does anyone have a good alternative that can do the same job on nexus 3 ?

Does nexus propose a workaround or a new feature that can be used instead ?

Will this issue be fixed one day ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to comment on the issue itself, rather than here?  It's a public Jira instance.

Comment: public Jira issue: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9862

Comment: At the end I have migrated our npm registry to Verdaccio and then we were able to upgrade to nexus 3.

Comment: The issue has progressed recently and looks like it will be released in v3.19

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this has finally been fixed (September 2019) and is available in Nexus version 3.19.

- [link to issue](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-9862)
- [link to fixes in version Nexus 3.19](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-21197?jql=project%20%3D%20NEXUS%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D%203.19.0)